# Inserting into a list of lists prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on a roster system project in prolog, and am using a modified search and insert structure based on an example provided by our professor. However, when I try to run my implementation of it, the provided record list is never inserted into the roster, even if there are no other elements present. I am not very familiar with prolog, and this issue is throwing me for a loop.

My implementation of the search/insert method is as follows:

```
search(_, [], 0).
search([X,_,_], [[X, _, _]|_], 1).
search([_,Y,_], [[_, Y, _]|_], 1).
search([X,Y,Z], [[_, _, _]|T], C) :- search([X, Y, Z], T, C).
searchinsert([X, Y, Z], L, L) :- search([X, Y, Z], L, 1).
searchinsert([X, Y, Z], L, [[X, _, _] | L]) :- search([X, Y, Z], L, 0).
searchinsert([X, Y, Z], L, [[_, Y, _] | L]) :- search([X, Y, Z], L, 0).
```

As designed, it should reject the provided record list if either the first or second element match that of another element in the roster. The function is called as follows:

```
process(4, X) :-
    nl,
    write('\tInsert student into roster.'), nl,
    read_student_info([A, B, C]),
    nl, nl, searchinsert([A, B, C], X, X).
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change the last call:

```
..., searchinsert([A, B, C], X, 1).
```

so X has a chance to be instantiated to a list. But you should rethink the 'data flow' of your process/2 driver, likely it's missing an argument.

Comment: What argument do you think I might be missing? The only information I have leading into the process/2 driver is the roster itself.

Comment: In Prolog, variables are 'assign once'. So, maybe you need another variable passed to process/2, that should get the updated roster.